# Is the ball of a reflexive space weakly metrizable?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, compactness

We know from Banach-Alaoglu that if $E^*$ is separable then the unit ball is metrizable with the weak topology.

Now is this true for reflexive spaces? I.e., if a Banach $E$ (eq. $E^*$) is reflexive, is its ball weakly-metrizable?

I suspect the answer is no. Is there an interesting counter-example?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try looking at a non-separable Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit ball in $E$ is metrizable with respect to the weak topology if and only if $E^*$ is separable. You can find the proof of this theorem in Brezis [Functional Analysis](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9780387709130), Theorem 3.29